# SNMP forwarder to reduce load of switch

Tags: network-interface, performance, snmp

I have a core switch and running SNMPv3 on this.
I need to reduce load of my switch. So if I have a SNMP Forwarder and do snmp on my core switch and other server snmp on my SNMP Forwarder, Do you know same application?
I found https://github.com/inexio/snmpfwd But may be it's discontinue.

Answer (score -1):

You have to create snmp as proxy. You can start from [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/using-snmp-proxy-debian-ronald-bartels).